# Selecting a specific number of rows, from a given cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to select a specific number of rows inside table.

I have something like this:

```
1
2 
3
4
5
6
=SUM()
```

How can I write the sum function so that it sums all the numbers in the cells from the row where =sum() function is, to upwards x rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of summing **three** cells above the location of the formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-4,COLUMN())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))
```

[image]

and by adjusting the **-1** and the **-4** you can select any part of the column above the formula cell

Answer (score 3):

The `OFFSET` function allows for this type of behavior.

Assuming the formula will be in cell `A7`, and you want to start summing with cell `A6`, and you want to include 5 cells above `A6`, the formula would look as follows:

`=SUM(OFFSET(A6,0,0,-5,1))`